# Calculations from Feature Server and display values

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, statistics

Using the ESRI JS API I would like to apply some basic math based on the Shape.area of a feature and then return that calculation to the web-page.  I can't see any reference to something even remotely similar to this on the ESRI API Reference page, so I am thinking that this will have to be done entirely using DOJO or DIJIT.  Can somebody please just nudge me in the correct direction.

Comment: I am thinking I might have two possible ways of doing this: 1 -  would be to create a GP service that would do the math and put the summary statistics into a table which I could display on my page with a dGrid. 2 - I am looking into the query API with out statistics [link](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#outstatistics) but this will only work if I can access the geometry information from the features.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JS API, you have several different options:

1. if the 'SHAPE.Area' field is exposed by the service you are working with, values can be retrieved as attributes of a graphic of interest.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#attributes

1. the API also provides a utility method to calculate the geodesic area of an input polygon (in geographic coordinate system).

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.geodesicutils-amd.html

1. lastly, you can also use an ArcGIS Server/AGOL geometry service to calculate accurate  area/length for input geometries in any coordinate system.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#areasandlengths

Comment: Hi John,  Thanks for the swift response.  The SHAPE field is not listed in REST as an available attribute - is this standard for ESRI - can I configure the service to display this?

Comment: i have edited my original answer to clarify that a 'SHAPE.Area' field could possibly be exposed by a REST service as opposed to the 'SHAPE' field which stores the actual geometry of the feature.

Comment: i have edited my original answer to clarify that a 'SHAPE.Area' field could possibly be exposed by a REST service as opposed to the 'SHAPE' field which stores the actual geometry of the feature.  if this isnt already visible, you could add it by checking the field as visible in your map document prior to republishing.

Comment: The shape fields were visible in the publishing map document.  I have submitted an ESRI Tech support request - will share the solution to this post once I have it.